# Make phpbb mysql query display all posts in a topic

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb

...as opposed to what it is doing at the moment, which is display the last reply from EACH topic in the speicified forum.

```
<?php
// How Many Topics you want to display?
$topicnumber = 10;
// Change this to your phpBB path
$urlPath = "../path/to/forum";

// Database Configuration (Where your phpBB config.php file is located)
include '../path/to/forum/config.php';

$table_topics = $table_prefix. "topics";
$table_forums = $table_prefix. "forums";
$table_posts = $table_prefix. "posts";
$table_users = $table_prefix. "users";
$link = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpasswd") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die("Could not select database");

$query = "SELECT t.topic_id, p.post_text, t.topic_title, t.topic_last_post_id, t.forum_id, p.post_id, p.poster_id, p.post_time, u.user_id, u.username
FROM $table_topics t, $table_forums f, $table_posts p, $table_users u
WHERE t.topic_id = 7 AND
f.forum_id = t.forum_id AND
t.forum_id = 11 AND
t.topic_status <> 2 AND
p.post_id = t.topic_last_post_id AND
p.poster_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC LIMIT $topicnumber";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed");                                   

print '<div class="news_block">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {


echo  "<h4><a href=\"$urlPath/viewtopic.php?f=$row[forum_id]&t=$row[topic_id]&p=$row[post_id]#p$row[post_id]\" TARGET=\"\">" .
$row["topic_title"] .
"</a> </h4>By: " .
$row["username"] . ' - ' . date("l", $row["post_time"]) .
"<p>" .
$row["post_text"] . // <----- 
"</p>";
}
print "</div>";
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);

/* date("l", $row["post_time"]) .  date('F j, Y, g:i a', $row["post_time"]) .*/
?>
```

As you might've been able to tell, I'm far from a coder. I think I've narrowed it down to p.post_id needing to be changed, but no matter what integer or variable I seem to assign to it, I can't get the desired effect. Would really appreciate some help at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to remove this part from the query:

```
AND p.post_id = t.topic_last_post_id
```

Right now you are asking for the post (only one) that has the same id as the last post of the topic, but you do not want to only get the last one. You want to get all posts.

Edit: 
You have to look at your database and check if there is any foreign key in your post table that refers to the topic.

Think of it that way: every forum has many topics, every topic has many posts and every post has exactly one user. So you have to have a connection between the tables that you can follow to identify how the rows match together.

Joins are very helpful in that way. If you work with a finished database schema that already contains those foreign keys, joins will help you to connect your queries.

This would be a well formed query supporting my explanations.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    $table_forums f
        LEFT JOIN
    $table_topics t ON t.forum_id = f.forum_id
        LEFT JOIN
    $table_posts p ON t.topic_id = p.topic_id
        LEFT JOIN
    $table_users u ON p.poster_id = u.user_id
WHERE
    t.topic_id = 7 AND t.forum_id = 11
        AND t.topic_status <> 2
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC
LIMIT $TOPICNUMBER
```

Comment: Hey bud thank you for taking the time to look at it. I have tried doing that a few times, and what it does is then outputs all posts made from every topic on the forums, and prints them to the page with the topic title of the intended topic, I hope that makes sense? So I have replies from EVERY topic on the forum. My guess is I need to further clarify that I want it to ONLY print from (in this case) Forum 11, Topic 7, but how to do that beyond what I've already got I do not know.

This is intially what led me to believe I have to further manipulate p.post_id somehow, but I'm lost for clues.

Comment: Got it. Does the post table has a fk that refers to the topic / forum it belongs to? You need to make sure the post is somehow connected to either the topic or the forum.

Comment: "fk"??  This is essentially what I'm trying to figure out I think. I thought "WHERE t.topic_id = 7 AND"   "t.forum_id = 11"  defined where the posts took from? In this cause, Forum 11, Topic 7. I tried out of desperation "p.post_id = t.topic_all_posts_id", and many MANY variations of that but pretty sure I was just making stuff up at that point lol

Comment: Foreign Key. Do you have access to your database schema? What you are looking for is a Join over three tables. Just have a look at the MySQL documentation about left join. What you are doing right now is to connect all posts with the information about topic 7 and forum 11. You actually already did it the right way with your user information. Poster_id is a foreign key of your user table and connects one user to one post. You will need the same thing to connect one post to one topic.

Comment: That.... is A LOT to take in. Umm. I guess I'll take a look over it, thank you. Although fwiw, I'm almost certain there's a "one command fix" here, I had it last night (only 99% sure, I'm learning all of this as I go so can't say 100%), changed all my code to incorporate a post externally button to actually put the table to use, and now I can't remember what for the life of me I had to set again.

Comment: If you screenshot your database schema here, I will take a look at it later and fix your query. Sorry for my short answers. I am on the run right now.

Comment: FOUND IT :D (with some help ^^) After deleting "AND p.post_id = t.topic_last_post_id " like you suggested, I changed "t.topic_id" to "p.topic_id" and it's working as intended. Will update code now. Thanks so much for your time mate.

Comment: Have a look at my edit. Are you sure it is working because there is still no "t.topic_id = p.topic_id" inside your query. You might still have an issue in your query...

Comment: Absolutely awesome catch, thank you so much for that alone! You're right, I was doing very very poor testing (I'm sorry!) and didn't have a 2nd topic in the forum, added one in and it all went to hell. Your query has fixed it and got it working as intended. Appreciate that so much, thank goodness I hadn't started creating all the pages yet.

Comment: Happy to hear. You are very welcome. Would be awesome if you could mark my post as the correct answer.